# 'Add image' option to image gallery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, image-gallery

I have am planning to use [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) the jquery lightbox plugin. I am just wondering as to what the best method would be to implement a 'add/upload image' option so it would be easy for a user to upload new images without having to go into the HTML markup and add an individual `<img>` line of code for each new image.

I am only currently knowledgeable with HTML and CSS at this current time. So if no one already has a snippet they could possibly provide me with, which language would be 'simpler' to learn for just for this specific task. Would it be PHP or Js or something different?

OR am I going about this completely wrong?

Comment: Where you want to upload the image?

Answer (score 0):

Of course they have to upload images to database. You need a suitable back end design. That means you need php to interact with database(or python will also do). If you need dummy upload procedures then you can easily do it with appendTo() method using jquery.

As you are using a plugin, then you will have a method to add an image to the webpage. It will be something like `$("user-uploaded-image").plugin-name();`

Answer (score 0):

Where you want to upload the image?

Uploading an image means transferring the image to another location (server). For that you need a server side script that

- Receives the image.
- Saves the image to server hard disk.

php is a server side scripting language.
JS is client side language that is used to sending requests (in this case image ) to server.

Just google it for getting sample image upload scripts.

Comment: The gallery would be displayed in a HTML page on the web hosting. So if  I were to get a upload script and designate a path to where it would be uploaded to, how can I make it automatically add to the gallery? As at the moment, following the authors method, each image is added manually via HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

From taking a look around google for upload scripts suggested by @kiren Siva I came across quite a few CMS type plugins that give me the ability to do exactly what I need.

Some examples can be found [here](http://www.design3edge.com/2010/08/26/best-free-and-open-source-php-image-galleries/).

Thank you all for your help and suggestions.